# Enabling 3D support on Ubuntu 11.04 guest in ESXi 5

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi

I'm having a heck of a time finding any support for this. I'd like to enable 3D support for a natty instance. The option is grayed out. Is there some magic voodoo that I have to perform to  enable this option?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, 3D acceleration for Linux guests is not available with this version of VMware. It was [only just added](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws90/doc/workstation-90-release-notes.html#OpenGL) with the recent release of Workstation 9. I haven't yet been able to confirm that it's available in vSphere Hypervisor 5.1 (formerly known as ESXi) though I suspect it would be.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a check here:

http://communities.vmware.com/thread/327250

Enable 3D Support checkbox will be shown on Video card settings  page in Virtual Machine Properties dialog. If the host does not support  3D the checkbox will be disabled.
3D checkbox will be enabled only if the following requirements must be met:

1. The host supports 3D acceleration
2. The host OS supports 3D acceleration i.e. meaning ESX 5.0 and higher.
3. The VM HW version is 8 and higher.

Once you enable the 3D support in the VM, power it on, once booted, make sure all  your DirectX features are enabled .i.e
following should be enabled :

1. DirectDrow Acceleration
2. Direct3D Acceleration
3. AGP Texture Acceleration.

you can use DirectX Diagnostic Tool to do this.  In Windows 7, it should be Enabled by default if the proper H/W is presented to it.

Once this is done, the installation and operatations of 3D Studio Max 2012 should go smooth.

Comment: Please next time include the relevant parts of the link in your post.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience my host does support 3D acceleration yet is unavailable when I use the template for Windows Server 2008 R2 if I switch to the Windows 7 Template the 3D acceleration works flawlessly. You could try selecting a different OS template and try it that way.
EDIT: you can also add "mks.enable3d=true" to the vmx file using Configurations Paramaters under options > general  on the edit settings screen of the virtual pc.

Comment: Might be helpful if the OP wasn't asking about how to do this on Ubuntu, and not "a different OS."